# How to get the name and props of global Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I understand that variable names are not intrinsic properties of an object and thus cannot be retrieved when passed through functions. But here is my use-case and I'd like to create a mapping between members of `UniversityEnums` and `displayStrings` to get the display string.

```
const UniversityEnums = {
studentStatus: {Enrolled: 'Enrolled', OnHold: 'OnHold', Expelled: 'Expelled'},
professorStatus: {FullTime: 'FullTime', PartTime: 'PartTime', Emeritus: 'Emeritus', Expelled: 'Expelled'}
};
```

and

```
const displayStrings = {
studentStatus_Enrolled: 'Student is enrolled in the program',
studentStatus_OnHold: 'Student decided not to participate',
studentStatus_Expelled: 'Student was expelled',
professorStatus_FullTime: 'Staff member is hired fulltime',
professorStatus_PartTime: 'Staff member is hired parttime',
professorStatus_Emeritus: 'Staff member is retired',
professorStatus_Expelled: 'Staff member was expelled'};
```

My goal is to write a function that grabs a member of `UniversityEnums` and returns the corresponding display string, for example:

```
const expelledStudentDispStr = getDispString(UniversityEnums.studentStatus.Expelled);
console.log(expelledStudentDispStr);
// Student was expelled
```

The code I currently have has two input arguments and is like `const expelledStudentDispStr = getDispString('studentStatus', UniversityEnums.studentStatus.Expelled);` which needs the name of the enum to get the value but I am looking for an even smarter way!

Thanks in advance.

**Note**: that I can manipulate the enum object (for example define it with different variable names (or *maybe, maybe,* append other properties to it or its children). *However*, I CANNOT change their values because those values are used to compare those statuses against other variables. Also, the `displayStrings` is coming from a third party source and modifying them for me is not doable *(at least easily!)*

**Possible workaround:**
One way that comes to my mind is to modify my enum object to have names that match `displayStrings` keys:

```
const UniversityEnums = {
studentStatus: {
    studentStatus_Enrolled: 'Enrolled',
    studentStatus_OnHold: 'OnHold',
    studentStatus_Expelled: 'Expelled'},
professorStatus: {
    professorStatus_FullTime: 'FullTime',
    professorStatus_PartTime: 'PartTime',
    professorStatus_Emeritus: 'Emeritus',
    professorStatus_Expelled: 'Expelled'}
};
```

Comment: Well you need to pass the student / professor bit around one way or another. You can't get it from the status you are giving to the function because expelled is in both of them.

Comment: Exactly, the ```expelled``` use-case that you pointed out is a valid one and I need to account for them. Also, please note that I can manipulate ```universityEnums```. (but the resources is returned from a third party resource which I cannot manipulate (at least easily!)

Comment: You can of course loop over your `UniversityEnums` to find the right one, but you could not distinguish the `Expelled` one.

Comment: @Bergi For that use-case cant we use object's properties to find out which parent does it belong? i.e. is it ```studentStatus``` or ```professorStatus```?

Comment: @AleX No, changing `getDispString(UniversityEnums.studentStatus.Expelled)` to `getDispString(UniversityEnums.studentStatus.studentStatus_Expelled)` does not help, because you're still passing the enum *value* and not a property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
getDispString(UniversityEnums.studentStatus.Expelled)
```

is the same as

```
getDispString("Expelled")
```

and it would still be the same with your new object as

```
getDispString(UniversityEnums.studentStatus.studentStatus_Expelled)
```

you don't give it more information, on the other hand you could transform your enum like that

```
const UniversityEnums = {
  studentStatus: {
    Enrolled: { 
      status: 'Enrolled',
      entity: 'student'
    },
    OnHold: { 
      status: 'OnHold',
      entity: 'student'
    },
    Expelled: { 
      status: 'Expelled',
      entity: 'student'
    }
  }
};
```

so you would give the extra information you need

you could do something like

```
for (const kind in UniversityEnums)
  for (const value in UniversityEnums[kind])
    UniversityEnums[kind][value] = {
       kind: kind,
       value: value
    }
```

from Bergi's answer

Answer (score 1):

> Note that I can manipulate the enum object

In that case, it's easy: just put unique values in the enums so that you can distinguish them properly. For example,

```
for (const kind in UniversityEnums)
  for (const value in UniversityEnums[kind])
    UniversityEnums[kind][value] = kind + '_' + value;
```

With that you can write

```
function getDispString(enumValue) {
  return displayStrings[enumValue];
}
```

Comment: Let me modify my question or add a note to it because I cannot change the values

Comment: @AleX_ What can you change? But then the answer is no, without changing the values it will not suffice to pass only a value to your `getDispString` function. (Of course there are other ways to change the values in more subtle ways that might make them distinguishable but their usage could stay the same).